# Passing an operator as an argument to a function in C

Tags: c

I want to pass greater than (>) and less than (<) operators as arguments to a function,how is it possible..is there any way to pass those operators as arguments..please any one can help me.

Comment: You can't directly. You need to pass in a representation of the operator (commonly using an enum) and the function then translates that to the right operator.

Comment: aaaaand we have the obligatory idiotic downvote on a perfectly reasonable question from a new user

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) much?

Answer (score 3):

You can do terrible things with macros, but in general, no, you can't do this. You typically accept a two argument function and call it, and that function can use `>` or `<` as appropriate, see [the `sort` docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) for an example.

That said, it's not super efficient (calling a function through a pointer can't be inlined, and for cheap operations like a `>` or `<` comparison, the function call overhead outweighs the comparison work). Making it efficient requires:

1. Multiple copies of the code, one for each possible operator (possibly generated via macros)
2. Moving to C++ and using templated code with functors/lambdas that can be inlined properly

Comment: Of course, technically, the C++ templated code is actually making multiple copies of the code too when it specializes the template. But it's doing so in a much safer way, only as needed, and it doesn't clutter the source code so badly, it just bloats the final binary size a bit.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to pass a 'raw' operator, but there are ways to achieve the same result.
The simplest would be a `char`

```
int func(char op, int a, int b)
{
    if (op == '<')
    {
        return a < b;
    }
    else if (op == '>')
    {
        return a > b;
    }
    return -l; /* error */
}
```

A more complex solution would be to use a function pointer to a function that does the operation (similar to the comparator used by the sort method).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a enum and pass it.
Or you can pass in a pointer to a comparison function like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max(int a, int b, int (*comp)(int, int)) {
  if (comp(a, b) < 0) {
     return b;
  } else {
     return a;
  }
}

int mycomp(int a, int b) {
  return a < b ? -1 : 1;
}

int main() {
  printf("%d %d\n", max(1, 2, mycomp), max(2, 1, mycomp));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this function by using `#define` and `#`. Character `#`, changes an operator to a string. (for example in `#define`, `#+` = `"+"`).

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define great(c) ((#c==">")? (1):(0))

int main()
{
    printf ("%d", great(>));
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, I passed `>` as a function argument.