# Is there a way to make functions take in an operator as an argument in c++?

Tags: c++, function, operators

Let's suppose I have a function as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
int func(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Without using an if else construct, suppose I want to generalize this function to take in an operator "-" that allows me to return a-b , is there a way for me to do it?

I came across the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734112/passing-an-operator-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c) with regard to C and thought it would be a good idea to know if there are any new features in C++ that make this a little easier?

In addition, is there a way for me to store an operator in a variable or pass a reference to it?

Comment: Use templates and pass a callable object instead. Many common operators already have [function objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional#Operator_function_objects) that can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in a limited fashion using templates and callable objects. Simply write the function using a template like so:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
int func(int a, int b, T op) {
  return op(a, b);
}

// Call the function here with type.
int main() {
  std::cout << func(5, 8, std::plus<int>());
}
```

You can pass any of [these](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional#Operator_function_objects) operator function objects in the manner I have shown.