# How to use a function defined using a macro

Tags: c++

I have defined the macro as follows

```cpp
#define COMPARE(OPERATOR, FUNCTION)                                         \ 
    template <typename T>                                                   \
    void FUNCTION(T *compArrayA, T *compArrayB, bool *resArray, int size) { \
        for (int idx = 0; idx <= size; ++idx ) {                                  \
            resArray[idx] = (compArrayA[idx] OPERATOR compArrayB[idx]);  \
        }                                                                   \
    }                                                                       \

COMPARE(==, eq);
COMPARE(!=, nq);
COMPARE(>=, greater_eq);
```

So, I tried to call the function defined in the macro as follows.

```cpp
float *ArrayA, *ArrayB;
bool *ArrayRes;

ArrayA = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float)* 100);
ArrayB = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float)* 100);
ArrayRes = (bool *) malloc(sizeof(bool) * 100);

eq(ArrayA, ArrayB, ArrayRes, 100);
```

I received the following error.

```
eq.h(11): error: expected an expression

1 error detected in the compilation of "eq.cpp".
```

eq.h(11) represents the following line.

```cpp
COMPARE(==, eq);
```

How do I define a function in a macro?

I just want to know how to implement functions using macros.

Comment: which line is `eq.h(11)`? did you remember to put your code that does things inside a function?

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us.

Comment: On another couple of notes, you have some other issues in the code you show... Like a one-off error in the loop which will cause it to go out of bounds; Using `malloc` instead of `new[]` (or better yet, `std::vector` or `std::array`); And using uninitialized values.

Comment: `i <= size` is suspicious, Do you mean `i < size`?

Comment: @user253751 Update ,which line is `eq.h(11)`

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`, and [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)?

Comment: @Eljay I Update the code.

Comment: your code works now http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6f8176606b4f6bf

Comment: Stop compilation after preprocessing, and look at what the macros have expanded to.

Comment: Assuming the code you show is copy-pasted, what happens in `eq.h` *above* the macro? At lines 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, don't do that. Since you've templates you can use standard library approach from [functional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) header

- [std::less](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less)
- [std::greater](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater)
- [std::less_equal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_equal)
- [std::greater_equal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater_equal)

without any macro definitions at all.

For example:

```
template<typename E, class Pred>                                                   
void vcompare(E *compArrayA, E *compArrayB, bool *resArray, int size) {
    for (int idx = 0; idx <= size; ++idx ) {                            
        resArray[idx] = Pred(compArrayA[idx], compArrayB[idx]);
    }                                                               
}

vcompare<int,std::less>(lhs,rhs,res,len);
vcompare<int,std::greater>(lhs,rhs,res,len);
```

P.S. Check [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) class and general [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) part inside standard C++ library.

Comment: Using `std::vector` and `std::transform` (as suggested in one comment) would make this even easier: `std::vector<float> v1(100), v2(100); std::vector<bool> res(100); std::transform(begin(v1), end(v1), begin(v2), begin(res), std::less<float>());`

Answer (score 1):

As you define your MACRO, you shouldn't use `;` after it, so

```
COMPARE(==, eq)
COMPARE(!=, nq)
COMPARE(>=, greater_eq)
```

instead of

```
COMPARE(==, eq);
COMPARE(!=, nq);
COMPARE(>=, greater_eq);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I removed the \ in the last line of the macro and removed the `;` in the macro declaration, but I still get the same error

Comment: @BoKuToTsuZenU • The code you've posted here is not the code that is producing the error you are experiencing.  Please provide a [mcve].  Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to pass operator as an argument.

**[Passing an operator as an argument to a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734112/passing-an-operator-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c/)**

As [Victor Gubin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9428851/victor-gubin) already answered it is best to avoid macro and embrace modern alternatives to do the same you are trying to achieve.